# python networkx eigenvector_centrality and eigenvector_centrality_numpy both not work for this gml

Tags: python, networkx

Just want to calculate the centrality eigenvector for my gml file.

I tried both method eigenvector_centrality and eigenvector_centrality_numpy.

But both of them give me the error message

When I tried eigenvector_centrality, the error is :

```
NetworkXError: eigenvector_centrality():
power iteration failed to converge in %d iterations."%(i+1))
```

I checked it may be fixed by using eigenvector_centrality_numpy when I tried it. I also got the error is :

```
line 375, in _raise_no_convergence
    raise ArpackNoConvergence(msg % (num_iter, k_ok, self.k), ev, vec)
scipy.sparse.linalg.eigen.arpack.arpack.ArpackNoConvergence: ARPACK error -1: No convergence (51 iterations, 0/1 eigenvectors converged) [ARPACK error -14: DNAUPD  did not find any eigenvalues to sufficient accuracy.
```

I know my network graph may special, but not so sure this type of network cannot be calculated the eigenvector centrality?

Thank you in advance for any help here.

Here is my gml file link: [enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19uvhY9Iiuog26M2i0h3bYmyuxhGZIbr5/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2):

I made change the dafault:

etol (float, optional) – Error tolerance used to check convergence in power method iteration.

tol=1e-06 to tol=1e-03 to make it work, but not quite sure why

eigenvector = nx.eigenvector_centrality(G, tol=1e-03)